# swift idForVendor, advertisingIdentifier

Tags: swift, uuid, ads, privacy

Is it possible to get and send advertisingIdentifier and/or idForVendor when some action takes place? For example user push button, and I write something like:

```
let advertisingIdentifier: NSUUID!
@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    print("You clicked the button")
    let addId = advertisingIdentifier().UUIDString
    let buttonIsPushedId = "THISBUTTONID"
    //send addId (my advertisingIdentifier) and buttonIsPushedId on some server    
}
```

Is it ok with Apple privacy terms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest reading Apple's App Store Review Guidelines, especially the section on Privacy:

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#privacy

In the intro:

> If you attempt to cheat the system (for example, ...steal data from
>   users, ...your Apps will be removed from the store and you will be
>   expelled from the developer program.

The Apple Developer Program License Agreement has quite a bit to say about the Advertising Identifier:

http://adcdownload.apple.com/Documentation/License_Agreements__Apple_Developer_Program/Apple_Developer_Program_Agreement_20150728.pdf

Section 1.2:

> is to be used solely for advertising purposes

Section 3.3.9:

> You may not use analytics software in Your Application to collect and
>   send device data to a third party. Further, neither You nor Your
>   Application will use any permanent, device-based identifier, or any
>   data derived therefrom, for purposes of uniquely identifying a device.

Section 3.3.12:

> You and Your Applications (and any third party with whom You have
>   contracted to serve advertising) may use the Advertising Identifier,
>   and any information obtained through the use of the Advertising
>   Identifier, only for the purpose of serving advertising. If a user
>   resets the Advertising Identifier, then You agree not to combine,
>   correlate, link or otherwise associate, either directly or indirectly,
>   the prior Advertising Identifier and any derived information with the
>   reset Advertising Identifier.

Section 3.3.13:

> For Applications compiled for any iOS version providing access to the
>   Ad Support APIs:
>   - You agree to check a user’s Advertising Preference prior to serving any advertising using the Advertising Identifier, and You agree to
>   abide by a user’s setting in the Advertising Preference; and
>   - If a user has set their Advertising Preference to limit ad tracking, You may use the Advertising Identifier, and any information obtained
>   through the use of the Advertising Identifier, only for Limited
>   Advertising Purposes.

Bottom Line: don't mess around with user privacy. It's a breach of trust with your users, and it may get your app rejected or pulled, or get you banned.